# How to implement the PHP function make_pipeline() as described in the question?

Tags: php

As part of a data processing pipeline, complete the implementation of the `make_pipeline` method:

The method should accept a variable number of functions, and it should return a new function that accepts one parameter `$arg`. The returned function should call the first function in the `make_pipeline` with the parameter `$arg`, and call the second function with the result of the first function.

The returned function should continue calling each function in the `make_pipeline` in order, following the same pattern, and return the value from the last function. For example:

```
$fun = Pipeline::make_pipeline(
    function($x) {
        return $x * 3;
    },
    function($x) {
        return $x + 1;
    },
    function($x) {
        return $x / 2;
    }
);
# should print 5
echo $fun(3);
```

```
class Pipeline
{
   public static function make_pipeline(...$funcs)
     {
        return function($arg) use ($funcs)
         {
             return NULL;
          };
     }
 }
```

Comment: you should revise your question I believe. :)

Comment: You should not just copy and paste an interview/test question. Some words from yourself saying something like "this is what I have started with, but got stuck" or "I have this test question I need help with..." something.

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would not help on a question that is either an interview question or homework without the OP trying their best to solve it, but it looks like you figured out part one of the puzzle, so I will see if I can help with the rest. If you think long and hard about this question and break down the instructions, you can pull it apart to figure out what to do:

> The method should accept a variable number of functions

*Something like `func_get_args()` would suffice here – EDIT: as noted by Paul Crovella, you can use what you already have ([splat operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics)) though I tend to use `file_get_args()`*

> should return a new function that accepts one parameter `$arg`

*So you need to return an anonymous function that accepts the first parameter to kick off the process*

> The returned function should continue calling each function in the make_pipeline in order

*This would suggest a loop of some kind*

> and return the value from the last function

*This would suggest you need to store a value that is always overwriting itself but also using itself as the arg to the next function*

That would leave you at something like:

```
class Pipeline
{
    public static function make_pipeline()
    {
        # The method should accept a variable number of functions
        $args       =   func_get_args();
        # should return a new function that accepts one parameter
        # you need to access the functions injected from the method so "use" is required
        $function   =   function($arg) use ($args)
        {
            # ...continue calling each function in the make_pipeline in order
            foreach($args as $function) {
                # You first need to store the triggering value in first function of args
                if(!isset($value))
                    $value  =   $function($arg);
                # Subsequent executions will now use the stored value and reset it simultaneously
                else
                    $value  =   $function($value);
            }
            # Send back this value
            return $value;
        };
        # Return our anonymous function
        return $function;
    }
}
```

You can test it out for yourself and see if it works, but you may want to try and dissect the question(s) you are given to find hints about what to do.

Comment: @PaulCrovella that was more for me, I use that operator on injection outside a function/method and use `func_get_args()` inside. I’ve just always done it, but yes, they have already taken care of it using the unpacking in the method definition.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above solution in Scala if it's helpful for any Scala developer who lands here. It can be achieved using foldLeft function:

```
object Pipeline {

  def compute[T](input: T, fn: T => T) = {
    fn(input)
  }
  def makePipeline[T](functions: (T => T)*)= (x: T) =>  {
    functions.foldLeft(x)((x, fn) => compute(x, fn))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println(makePipeline((x: Int) => x * 3, (x: Int) => x + 1, (x: Int) => x / 2)(3))
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I was trying to figure out this in Scala